# How to add other supported devices to android store

Tags: android, google-play, device

Hey basically i done some of my testing on my HTC wildfire and the application worked fine but for some reason it is not supported in the device list is there any way i could contact google to make it supported ?

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why an app is not supported by the Wildfire is that you forgot to add compatibility for small screens to your manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Don't blame Google ;-)